# web.xml - Java Servlet Filters - Not being run before processing the JSP page (on Tomcat)

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, web.xml, servlet-filters

I am fairly new to Servlet Filters and have basically joined a project using them and added an additional filter to the `web.xml` file (deployed on *Tomcat 5.5*).

I am 95% sure that at some point it was working correctly but now when debugging if I put breakpoints at the top of the JSP page I am trying to view (`login.jsp`), it's template page (`page.jsp`) and within both of the configured filter's `doFilter()` method; it runs through the whole of the `login.jsp` page (top to bottom), then `page.jsp` and the starts processing the filters.

I need it to run the filters first, since one of them determines the language the page should be displayed in (checking cookies, db settings and browser settings) which should then apply to the `login.jsp`.

Has anyone got any suggestions as to what might be going wrong?

There is a lot of code I could be posting but am not convinced that would be of any use since it's all working just in the wrong order.

Snippets from the web.xml:

```
<web-app>
...
<filter>
        <filter-name>SetSecurityContextFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>
            com.section2.SecurityContextServletFilter
        </filter-class>
    </filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>SetLocaleFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        com.section2.locale.LocaleServletFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>trinidad</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.webapp.TrinidadFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter>
    <filter-name>ActiveUserFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.section2.ActiveUserFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>trinidad</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SetSecurityContextFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>SetLocaleFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>ActiveUserFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/pages/section2/user/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

...
</web-app>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You had a look at http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/Filters.html and http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/Filter.html ? Without knowing what you do, it's hard to imagine what went wrong. Have you tried another servlet container like jetty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your replies - I have now understood the issue fully...it only happens for the login.jsp page, none of the other pages. And in my case, the `login .jsp` page is a special case because it is usually viewed as a result of a redirect.

In the `web.xml`:

```
<login-config>
        <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
        <form-login-config>
            <form-login-page>/login.jsp</form-login-page>
            <form-error-page>/login.jsp?error=true</form-error-page>
        </form-login-config>
    </login-config>
```

And I presume because of this, the filters are not hit in the usual order! Added a call from the login page to do what the filter does and all is well.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 8):

How is the `Filter` code organized? Are you maybe calling first `FilterChain#doFilter()` and only thereafter doing the needed logic?

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
    // Any code here will be executed BEFORE passing request through JSP/Servlet.
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
    // Any code here will be executed AFTER passing request through JSP/Servlet.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the filter's weren't called for login.jsp is that Tomcat's interpretation of the spec is that authentication is part of the container, not part of the webapp, and so occurs outside the role of filters. Hence filters aren't applied to the login page (login.jsp in this case) or j_security_check.

ref: https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=21795 - the title only references j_security_check, but the discussion covers the whole form-based authentication mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

One obvious error is in the trinidad filter mapping. It should not have a servlet-name, but a url-pattern.

Comment: It's perfectly valid. It only means that the particular filter is coupled with the servlet in question and thus only invoked on the same url-pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem when I wrote:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
   if(...) {
      response.sendRedirect(url);
   }
   chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

instead

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) {
   if(...) {
      response.sendRedirect(url);
      return;
   }
   chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```